# Nvidia gets a black screen after a few seconds on a game

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

I have a `geforce gt 630` and Ubuntu 14.04. I installed the driver using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update sudo
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```

It works fine, but a few seconds after I start a game in steam, I get a black screen, while the music continues to play.

I tried [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Screen_Blanks.2BAC8-Monitor_Turns_Off), "Screen Blanks/Monitor Turns Off" section (I use a DVI to VGA adapter).

My xorg.config currently:
[image]

Did I do anything wrong? Are those `xorg.conf.save`, and `xorg.conf.save.1`, supposed to exist?

Well it is not steam, i tried the same game without steam and got the same problem, i have tried also tried Strife and got this problem on the launcher! is not even full screen.

Comment: could you replace the image by the actual (textual) code? You can paste the output of the terminal into your question, select it and click the `<$>` button above the edit window.

Comment: What is strange is that other games through the program central like hedgears and executed without any problem, and everything else, programs ,movies etc runs perfectly except the games on steam, and if i unnistall the nvidia driver, i can run the games on steam without any problem